# Что принимает функция float (func4(double)(void))[10]?

Tags: c, функции

Первый раз вижу такой вид функции,можете объяснить что она принимает? Число с точкой и массив  void?

Comment: Интересно, а тот человек, который поставил "-", может сам ответить на этот вопрос :). Компенсирую "-" плюсом, ибо сам не уверен в собственной интерпретации :)

Comment: @RandomDude Это не корректное объявление, которое не будет компилироваться.

Comment: Здесь нет никакой "функции". Это синтаксически бессмысленный текст. Он ничего не значит вообще.

Comment: Если бы не было каста во `float`, то такое выражение (не декларация!) было бы возможно, а `float(...)[10]` это бессмыслица.

Comment: @Александр Муксимов, по-моему, так минус вполне справедливо поставили. Если бы был приведен реальный код, то можно было бы что-то обсуждать. А так это очередной вопрос непонятно о чем. Я, пожалуй проголосую за закрытие.

Comment: @freim у меня нет сейчас возможности проверить верность синтаксиса (я следовал презумпции добросовестности для задающих вопросы) поэтому снимаю свой "+". В определениях на ссылки на массивы функций встречаются "жуткие конструкции", поэтому я отверг сомнения в ошибочности кода. P.S. "+" снять не могу, ибо вопрос уже заблокирован.

Comment: Есть интересный инструмент, который помогает переводить с C на English: cdecl.org.

Comment: @freim: Не вижу нигде даже отдаленного подобия "каста во float". О чем речь?

Comment: @AnT, `type(expression)`, это т.н. [Explicit type conversion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast). Собственно, его мы и наблюдаем в форме `float(...)`.

Comment: @freim Во-первых, вопрос помечен тегом C. В языке С ничего подобного нет. Во-вторых даже в С++ этот синтаксис неоднозначен и вне контекста нельзч сказать, что это такое.